# Matplotlib setting `axes` object with `imshow` causes y-axis to become variable

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

**Description**

I have began refactoring some code based on the future warning of matplotlib, to re-use the initially defined `axes` object. However, I noticed that whenever I was re-using my `axes` object, the image size would be variable. Since, I have managed to isolate the problem to the `axes.imshow` method as after using `imshow`, the y-axis of any subsequent drawing on that axes has a y-axis that seems to rescale.

The feeling I have is that the y-axis scale is retained from the initial image that is plotted using `imshow` (I thought that `axes.clear` should reset this). Specifically in the below examples, shuffling plots some data spanning ~ 9.90 to 10.10 but because the original image spanned form 0 to 50 the y-axis is barely visible.

Below are first two screenshots of the expected and then 'bugged' behaviour, followed by an MVCE that has two sections that can be toggled to get the expected or 'bugged' behaviour:

**Images**

1. Splash without `imshow`:
   [image]
2. Screen after 'Foo -> Shuffle' (Expected behaviour):
   [image]
3. Splash with `imshow`:
   [image]
4. Screen after 'Foo -> Shuffle' (unexpected behaviour):
   [image]

**MVCE**

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (
    FigureCanvasTkAgg
)
import tkinter as tk
from matplotlib import image, figure
from numpy import random, linspace
from os import path, getcwd
from pylab import get_cmap

class Foo(object):
    @classmethod
    def run(cls):
        root = tk.Tk()
        Foo(root)
        root.mainloop()

    def __init__(self, master):
        # Figure & canvas
        self.fig = figure.Figure(figsize=(5,5))
        self.axes = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, master=master)
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=tk.YES)

        # Splash image (This 'bugs')
        Z = random.random((50,50))
        self.axes.imshow(Z, cmap=get_cmap("Spectral"), interpolation='nearest')
        self.canvas.draw()

        # Dummy start data (This Works)
        #self.axes.plot(random.normal(10,0.05,100))
        #self.canvas.draw()

        # MENU
        menu = tk.Menu(master)
        master.config(menu=menu)
        test_menu = tk.Menu(menu, tearoff=0)
        menu.add_cascade(label="Foo", menu=test_menu)
        test_menu.add_command(label="Shuffle",
                              command=self.shuffle)
        test_menu.add_command(label="Add",
                              command=self.add)

    def add(self):
        x_data = linspace(0,10, 1000)
        y_data = random.normal(x_data)
        self.axes.plot(x_data, y_data)
        self.canvas.draw()

    def shuffle(self):
        self.axes.clear()
        self.axes.plot(random.normal(10,0.05,100))
        self.canvas.draw()


if __name__ == "__main__":
   Foo.run()
```

**Question**

What is going on here, specifically what is causing the image to appear so differently and what can be done about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When no argument is given for `aspect`, it defaults to `None`. From the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html):

> If None, default to rc image.aspect value

Therefore if no argument is given to imshow, it will use whatever the rcParam for "image.aspect" is, which you can find by doing:

```
print (plt.rcParams["image.aspect"])  # default is "equal"
```

A fix to your problem would be to set it to "auto" in your `shuffle` function using  `axes.set_aspect()`:

```
def shuffle(self):
    self.axes.clear()
    self.axes.plot(random.normal(10,0.05,100))
    self.axes.set_aspect("auto")
    self.canvas.draw()
```

If you don't mind changing the aspect ratio of imshow, there is also an `aspect=` argument:

```
self.axes.imshow(Z, cmap=get_cmap("Spectral"), interpolation='nearest', aspect="auto")
```

Comment: I didn't realize that `imshow` changed the aspect, this indeed caused the problem. However, I have opted to set it in the initial `imshow` line as follows: `self.axes.imshow(Z, aspect='auto')`.

Comment: @BasJansen  Yes that's also an option. I've updated the answer with that too

Comment: Perfect, I have accepted your answer as it fixed my problem. However, I'm still trying to wrap my head around why this happens as the default of the parameter is `None` which should then inherit `image.aspect` (as per imshow documentation) but as the image.aspect isn't explicitly set shouldn't it also be `None`? *confused face*

Comment: In most cases, `None` in matplotlib means "the default". For `imshow` the default aspect is `"equal"`. The aspect is propagated through to the axes. Once the axes aspect has been set, it'll keep that setting until you change it again. This is what this answer does via `self.axes.set_aspect("auto")`.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest So if `imshow` defaults to "equal" does that mean it overrides `rcParams["image.aspect"]`?

Comment: No, sorry. It defaults to `rcParams["image.aspect"]` of course and that is `"equal"` by default.