# Matplotlib axes.legend changes image size (image aspect?)

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, legend, axes

This question is most likely related to a previous question I had that arose during refactoring some code (to re-use the matplotlib axes object) that is linked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52202758/1093485). That question described an issue where using `imshow` would adjust the `image.aspect` parameter.

I am now encoutering an issue that gives a similar effect but I have been unable to fix it by forcing the `image.aspect` parameter to auto, which was my first thought as it looks like that is being adjusted somehow. I have also been unable to find anything digging through the underlying documentation found [here](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.legend.html).

Here are **pictures** illustrating the issue (Obscured legend entries):

Expected behaviour (limited number of legend entries)
[image]

Unexpected behaviour (large number of legend entries)
[image]

A **MVCE** for the above behaviour (with utter nonsense data) is listed below, where the behaviour can be toggled between expected and unexpected (for me) by toggling the upper limit in the  `for i in range(1,10):` line to 50.

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (
    FigureCanvasTkAgg
)
import tkinter as tk
import numpy
from matplotlib import image, figure

class Foo(object):
    @classmethod
    def run(cls):
        root = tk.Tk()
        Foo(root)
        root.mainloop()

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.fig = figure.Figure(figsize=(12,6))
        self.fig.set_tight_layout(True)
        self.axes = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        self.axes.axis('off')
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, master=master)
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=tk.YES)
        self.canvas.draw()
        self.data = []
        # Adjust the upper value to 10 or 50
        for i in range(1,10):
            self.axes.plot(range(0,100),numpy.random.randint(1,100,100), label=str(i))
        self.axes.legend()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Foo.run()
```

I would love to get a hint as to what parameter or setting I am struggling with this time.

Comment: I think this is due to a combination of adding lots of legend entries which is changing the layout of the figure when used with `self.fig.set_tight_layout(True)`

Comment: @DavidG That does seem to be the case, however I would like to keep the behaviour of `fig.set_tight_layout` to have the figure fill the entire Canvas(/Axes?) if possible.

Comment: A less than ideal alternative would be to remove the `self.fig.set_tight_layout(True)` and adjust the whitespace yourself using `self.fig.subplots_adjust()`

Comment: @DavidG That indeed can work, so am I correct in understanding that `set_tight_layout` determines the size of the image including the legend and somehow adjusts the size of the image alone so that the combination fits on the page with as little padding as possible?

Comment: What version of `matplotlib` are you using?

Comment: @DavidG I am using 2.2.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here `tight_layout`  is trying to fit every artist drawn, into the figure with as little padding as possible. When the number of legend entries is very large this will give some undesired results.

In matplotlib versions > 3 an artist has a property `set_in_layout` ([docs for tight_layout](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.tight_layout)) which you can set to either True or False to include or omit it from the calculations done when `tight_layout` is called. Therefore you can modify your `__init__` to look something like:

```
def __init__(self, master):
    self.fig = figure.Figure(figsize=(12,6))
    self.fig.set_tight_layout(True)
    self.axes = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
    self.axes.axis('off')
    self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, master=master)
    self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=tk.YES)
    self.canvas.draw()
    self.data = []
    # Adjust the upper value to 10 or 50
    for i in range(1,50):
        self.axes.plot(range(0,100),numpy.random.randint(1,100,100), label=str(i))
    self.leg = self.axes.legend()
    self.leg.set_in_layout(False)  # set to False so it's not used in tight_layout calculation!
```

An alternative (but less than ideal) option would be to remove `self.fig.set_tight_layout(True)` and adjust the whitespace yourself using [`self.fig.subplots_adjust()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.subplots_adjust), however this may require some manual tweaking of the parameters to get the desired result.